# How to get external screen list and connect to on iOS

Tags: ios, airplay

I want to create an app, has Air Play feature. **I want add a button, when user click to that button, a list of external screens appear, then user choose a screen, then I can show content to that external screen.** I realise that **YouTube** can do that, but I cannot found a document, demo or tutorial tell me how to do.

[image]

I can only share my content to external screen if user connect to external screen manual, use Control Center. Some below tutorial also can do that only:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/57161/airplay-tutorial
https://github.com/quellish/AirplayDemo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Use `MPVolumeView`. It has a volume slider and a Air Play chooser button.

```
MPVolumeView *myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
myVolumeView.showsVolumeSlider = NO; // use it if don't want to show slider
[self.view addSubview: myVolumeView];
```